# Replacing by GREP

Tags: adobe-indesign

I want to replace a specific space (that one after single letter) and replace it with non-breaking space, but I don't know how.

I tried using `\s[\l\u]\s`, but I don't know what to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your find to:

```
(\s[\l\u])\s
```

Change to:

```
$1~S
```

English translation:

put into memory, space followed by any letter (end memory), that is followed by any space. Replace by stuff in memory followed by nonbreaking space.

Comment: @Wolff Right, thanx, fixed.

Comment: Thanks a millions, it worked.